# Python2 Packages not recoganised by Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I have installed both python2.7 and python3.5 in my Ubuntu. I mostly use Python3.5 only. I was trying to import some libraries and use them in my program

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
n = input()
print(n)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(str(n))))
```

When I run this code with `Python3 filename.py` I am getting a package not found error.Then I tried running it with `Python filename.py` then I am getting the desired output. Then I added the `input()` line and tried to run it and it started throwing an error because `input()` was introduced only in `Python3`

Then I tried to locate the pacakages that I have installed namely "PIL(python3-imaging), tesseract, pytesseract" and their location goes something like `usr/local/lib/Python/`. Since I am new to this packages and stuff my guess is that the erroris caused because they are installed in `Python2.7` related files and not in `Python3` files.

How can I solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line to install the package you want to use

```
python3 -m pip install PIL tesseract pytesseract
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install pip3

Comment: Yep sorry..Shouldn't have posted without googling..I am installing pip now(very slow internet connection). I will get back to you with the results.

Comment: then you may use pip3 directly